# Apply TimeZone to a specific date?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

For example, server time is 11 pm.
User timezone, specified within the app, is `US Mountain Standard Time`.

So I need to get 4 pm, user time.

Tried with

```
var UserTimeZoneInfo = "US Mountain Standard Time";
var userTime  =TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(now, _UserTimeZoneInfo);
```

and this

```
var userTime  = new DateTimeOffset(now, this._UserTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset);
```

but in both cases, I get 8am instead of 4pm. TimeZone difference gets added to server time , instead of subtracted. I see there are other DateTime functions, but not sure which one to use ?

Comment: not sure you really read what that function does?  Also, you'll save yourself a lot of nightmares if you use DateTimeOffset.

Comment: No, that's why I asked a question.

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." Try [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/type-choices). Try again; Try again. It's sometimes well worth it.

Comment: `ConvertTimeToUtc` converts local time to utc 
And you are using it to do otherwise. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `BaseUtcOffset` is the zone's "standard" offset from UTC, so the second line wouldn't be correct in the general sense (Arizona doesn't observe DST, so might otherwise work in the specific sense).  What's the value of `now`, please?  Including the `DateTimeKind`.

Comment: You need to use ConvertTimeFromUtc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FromUTC not ToUTC!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ConvertTimeFromUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method if you want change to specified timezone time from UTC.

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime arizonaTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 23, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc), timeZone);
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKWt96)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConvertTime which Converts a time to the time in a particular time zone.

```
     DateTime currentDt = DateTime.Now;
     var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
     var userTime  = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDt, timeZone);
```